# How to set up google analytics account service?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm new in using Google Analytics API and I'm facing a problem.
i got the error labeled as  (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account.
With my google account I am able to view google anaytics pages and by code, I just can't.

Here is my code. i think I misused something in the 6 first lines, but what ?
Any idea is welcomed.

```
$scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics";
$client_id = "[12 numbers]-[32 letters/numbers].apps.googleusercontent.com";
$service_account_name = "[same 12 numbers]-[same 32 letters/numbers] @developer.gserviceaccount.com";
$key_file_location = "./google-account-service.p12";
$projectId = "[same 12 numbers]";
$projectName = "[my project name defined in console.developers.google.com]";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($projectName);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($service_account_name, array($scope), $key);  

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()){
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$client->getAccessToken();

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// metrics
$_params[] = 'date';
$_params[] = 'date_year';
$_params[] = 'date_month';
$_params[] = 'date_day';
// dimensions
$_params[] = 'visits';
$_params[] = 'pageviews';
$_params[] = 'bounces';
$_params[] = 'entrance_bounce_rate';
$_params[] = 'visit_bounce_rate';
$_params[] = 'avg_time_on_site';

$from = date('Y-m-d', time()-2*24*60*60); // 2 days
$to = date('Y-m-d'); // today

$metrics = 'ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces,ga:entranceBounceRate,ga:visitBounceRate,ga:avgTimeOnSite';
$dimensions = 'ga:date,ga:year,ga:month,ga:day';
$data = $service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$projectId, $from, $to, $metrics, array('dimensions' => $dimensions));

foreach($data['rows'] as $row) {
   $dataRow = array();
   foreach($_params as $colNr => $column) echo $column . ': '.$row[$colNr].', ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the service account mail that you use is not valid. You need to create a project in console.developers.google.com and activate the api for google analytics. then you will get acces to you service account email use it in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

I have created a project in https://console.developers.google.com/project , enabled GA in APIs, created an oauth2 client of type "service account" in "credentials" menu, downloaded the p12 file, copy the client id & email address in my below code.

What did I forget to do ?

Answer (score 0):

just a tip i noticed in your code u set the $projectid = the first 12 number as in the $clientid which is as far as i know wrong .. the $projectid must be equal to ( go to your google analytics account , take a look at the URL you will notice there is a segment looks like /a39569200w68518820p70543179/ take the numbers after the 'p' letter in this case the 70543179 numbers and set them as a value for $projectid variable ) i dont know if it solve your problem but i think you should know ..